# Handling QDialog's events safely in PyQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I'm having troubles with a Qt Application (managed through PyQt5) which used to be reliable, until a bunch of updates (where I ended up with PyQt6). PyQt6 is not the culprit here, as I began to have those problems with later PyQt5 versions.

I'm suspecting my problems are instead linked to an abuse of `exec()` methods call. The full traceback is not available (I've only a RuntimeError with a cryptic message telling me the Dialog is not available anymore); what (I think) I'm seeing are the parent windows randomly disappearing. This behaviour is indeed mentionned in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdialog.html#exec):

> Note: Avoid using this function; instead, use open(). Unlike exec(), open() is asynchronous, and does not spin an additional event loop. This prevents a series of dangerous bugs from happening (e.g. **deleting the dialog's parent while the dialog is open via exec()**). When using open() you can connect to the finished() signal of QDialog to be notified when the dialog is closed.

Initially, my app was constructed this way:

```
QMainWindow A > QDialog B > QDialog C > ...
```

Each QDialog was launched using `.exec()` method.

The pseudo code could be summarized this way **[edit]** :

```
class A(QMainWindow):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.ui = Some_Ui_From_QtDesigner()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.some_menu.triggered.connect(self.load_popup)

  def load_popup():
    B = QDialog(A)
    if B.exec() == 1:
      # Do some things (extract data from B and update A)
      if C.exec() == 1:
        # Do some things (extract data from C and update B)

qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
a = A()
a.show()
qApp.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
qApp.exec()
```

I've tried to use `.open()` methods instead of `.exec()` and came up with something like this (using QLoopEvent's and events handling):

```
def process_C_qdialog(parent):

    C = QDialog(parent)
    # Construct your QDialog some more ...
    
    loop = QtCore.QEventLoop()
    my_result = None
    def _accept():
        my_result = "blah"
        loop.exit(0)
            
    def _reject():
        loop.exit(-1)
        
    f.accepted.connect(_accept)
    f.rejected.connect(_reject)
    f.open()
    loop.exec()
    return my_result
```

My troubles are far from over as yet. I suspect that recreating manually a QEventLoop causes the same problems than using `.exec()` in the first place.

So some questions:

- Am I right about the QEventLoop?
- Would it be safer/enough to leave the parent out of the QDialog generator?
- Any advice on how to handle this the right way (keeping a modal dialog if possible)?
- More generally, are they any safe ways to reproduce the static methods of Qt through a custom python function? (ie, a function which would load a customized popup, wait for the user's input and returning it)

*Note: as this behaviour happens erratically (and without the full traceback available), I'm not 100% sure of this; but I suspect that even a simple `QMessageBox().exec()` has the same effects, even if this is not stated in the doc.*

Comment: I think that your initial usage of `exec`s was fine. Using `exec` is fine as long as you do not do any "wild" things with the dialogs... I think you should create a minimal reproducible example with the `exec`s and then lets look at your problem. Your other attempt with event loops looks terrible, this is definitely not a well maintainable code. If you really want to use `open` and write asynchronous code, then just write asynchronous code and do not try to force it to work like synchronous.

Comment: Multiple nested event loops are often doomed to fail. Using `open()` is the proper choice for complex situations, but you need to just use signals instead of event loops.

Comment: Care to follow that insight with an exemple @musicamante ? accepted/rejected are signals already, but I think I need a nudge in the right direction...

Comment: @alexpdev : thanks for the feedback; I'll try to complete that asap, but I'm not so sure a minimal reproducible example will be usefull. As I said, this happens randomly (I'm not sure which level of deepness triggers it or even if this is the trigger) ; in fact, my code (the first as well as the second) works out perfectly 9 out of 10 times. If I had been able to isolate the problem, posting a MRE would have been my first step indeed.

Comment: Thanks @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager for the advice. As I have not been able to find exactly what "a wild thing" would be (though I have tried...), I'd be interested on more detailed answers (even if it means more general than practical advice.)

Comment: @musicamante In the original code he is not nesting `exec`s. He only has the main window and one dialog's `exec`. Once the `exec` has finished, he opens another dialog with its `exec`. So there is no nesting of `exec`s, it is a series of `exec`s. He uses one exec after another. Of course this could go wrong if he did some crazy stuff like deleting the main window from the dialog. But if it is just a normal modal dialog requesting some values from the user, then I do not see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager ok, if deleting the parent is the kind of thing you thought of, I was **not** doing that. Well, I'll try to come back with a more complete example...

Comment: @tgrandje My advice would be: use `exec`s for simple stuff. Use `open` for more complex stuff but do not try to abuse event loops like you did, because you will only end up is a solution which is probably worse than the original `exec`. Use signals and slots instead to react to `finished`, `accepted` or `rejected` signals. And one more advice: if you target multiplatform, then test the modal dialogs on all platforms, they tend to behave a bit different on each of them, especially macOS is a bad boy...

Comment: @tgrandje There are certainly more possible problems than just deleting the parent. For example I had troubles with some background job running in a thread which was processing data and if some error occurred, then it showed up a modal dialog. And if more such background jobs were running, then I sooner or later ended up with two or more modal dialogs blocking each other. One was obscuring the other but I could not close it because the other was the one which was getting all user events... But this is the "complex" stuff which I was talking about.

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager well, the pseudo-code is a bit confusing (`A` is called a "QMainDialog"), but, in any case, they are nested in the sense of a basic `dialog.exec` that is started with the main event loop, and with "multiple" I also mean *consecutive* (sorry for being imprecise): there are occasions for which event loops might slightly "collide" in unexpected ways, like the peculiar example [of this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/72629726/2001654), which, even if it doesn't properly use parentship, is *still* valid.

Comment: @tgrandje you have to connect the *child* dialog's signal *from* the parent *to* the parent's functions that eventually do the desired stuff; it may complicate your code a bit, but it's also a preferred approach for "layered" dialogs. About your comment to alexpdev, I understand that the behavior is unpredictable and erratic, but trying to create a basic MRE that *does* reproduce the issue (even if it only happens randomly) based on your pseudo-code might be useful anyway.

Comment: @musicamante thanks for your insights they are very helpful. I'm starting to think I didn't ask the right question. Maybe what SO is missing is a kind of do's and (more to the point) don't with `exec`. Qt's doc is not helpful and most advice on SO sums up to "don't do wild things, but it's mostly ok to use it"... Do you thing such a question would be accepted on SO (as it would be kinda vague) ?

Comment: @tgrandje this question is fine, the code is the issue (both have issues, like the a strange indentation, an unknown class name, or missing references). The Qt docs are a bit confusing on these aspects, especially because, while PyQt/PySide usually work seamlessly with the C++ API, there are some C++ aspects that are "ignored" in Python that could clarify the *underlying flow* of events, also considering memory management and object destruction. A more "open" question might be acceptable, as long as it provides proper code and use cases (but expanding this one might also suffice).

Comment: @musicamante Agreed, I've fixed the code (though it doesn't really affects the questions at the end). But more to the point, what has been invaluable so far are the comments you (and HiFile) have left as they clarify when exec should be avoided. I've rewritten my code with that in mind (hence the delay) and may have found the source of my bugue (I now suspect the garbage collector, only time will will tell). I've almost closed the question (which won't go very much further obviously), but I'd say SO would benefit from a complete answer synthetizing your comments. Would you care for it ?